# If $x_1,x_2$ are standard normal variates and Z=$x_1^2$$x_2$,what will be the correlation between Z and $x_1$?

Tags: self-study, correlation, normal-distribution

Will appreciate it if you give some tips about how to approach this problem;Will the product $z$= $x_1^2$ $x_2$ be standard normal also?

Comment: *Assuming* $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent, the joint distribution of $(x_1, x_1^2x_2)$ is (obviously) the same as that of $(x_1, x_1^2(-x_2)).$  Thus the correlation coefficient (if it exists at all) must equal its own negative.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that you are taking $x_1$$x_2$ to be independent. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to solve this without knowing the correlation $\rho$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$. It is not the case that $x_1^2$$x_2$ is standard normal.

To calculate the correlation between Z and $x_1$ you would calculate

$E[(x_1^2$$x_2$-0)($x_1$-0)]/{$sqrt$[$Var(x_1^2$$x_2$)$Var(x_1$)]}. We note that $E(x_1^2$$x_2)$=0 and $E(x_1$)=0 and $Var(x_1$)=1.

So that leaves only $E[(x_1^2$$x_2$$x_1$)] = $E(x_1^3 x_2)$=$E(x_1^3) E(x_2)$ because $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent. Also because $x_1$ is standard normal $E(x_1^3)$=0. You also need to calculate $Var(x_1^2 x_2)$.

Comment: So we can see the answer would be 0.But can you guide me on how to find the variance of $x_1^2$$x_2$.i know E($x_1^2$$x_2$)=0 ,but how do i get E($x_1^4$$x_2^2$)

Comment: Use independence again.

Comment: So as Glen_b notes using independence gives $E(x_1^4 x_2^2)$ = $E(x_1^4) E(x_2^2)$ =$E(x_1^4)$. So what is the 4th moment of a standard normal distribution?

Comment: i am getting the 4th moment to be 3